# HeatMap for User History Tracking

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-visualization, heatmap

Is there any open source libraries or just examples, using javascript or jquery, on how to create heatmap for tracking user history for socially aware website users, such as (github users contribution activity):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implements an activity heatmap, which shows activity levels on a calendar. 
https://github.com/gyaikhom/activitymap

there ist more when you google something like:
"d3 js calendar"